# Windows IoT Core recovery - administrator password

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, windows-iot-core-10

I'm reading [Windows 10 IoT Core Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-hardware/service/iot/recovery#recovery-using-built-in-safe-os).

> In this method, the device contains a safe OS in a separate partition. Based on the location of the recovery SW, there can be few options.

What is the administrator password after the process is finished?

Answer (score 1):

The default password of administrator is **p@ssw0rd**.